# Ruby simple interactive interpreter

Tags: programming-challenge, ruby

This is a solution to this problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/53005a7b26d12be55c000243/train/ruby

The task is to make a simple interpreter that will take expressions and calculate the results. I'm just looking for general feedback on following Ruby standard practices and ways I could shorten the code by omitting parentheses for example:

```rb
class Interpreter

  def input expr
    if expr.strip == ""
      return ""
    end
    # puts expr
    tokens = tokenize(expr).map{ |a| a[0] }    
    parsedTokens = parseTokens tokens
    if parsedTokens.length == 1
      if !@variables.key? parsedTokens[0].name
        raise 'unitialized variable'
      end
      return @variables[parsedTokens[0].name]
    end
    # todo can the user enter just a number?
    leastPrecedentNode = partition parsedTokens
    rootOfBuiltTree = buildTree leastPrecedentNode
    result = calculateRecursive rootOfBuiltTree
    result
  end

  private

  class OperatorInfo
      @@operators = { '=' => 0, '+' => 1, '-' => 1, '*' => 2, '/' => 2, '%' => 2 }
      @@assignmentOperator = '='

      def self.operators
        @@operators
      end

      def self.assignmentOperator
        @@assignmentOperator
      end
  end

  class ParseUnit
    attr_reader :overallIndex
    attr_reader :nestLevel
    attr_reader :indexInLevel

    def initialize(overallIndex, nestLevelArg, indexInLevelArg)
      @overallIndex = overallIndex
      @nestLevel = nestLevelArg
      @indexInLevel = indexInLevelArg
    end
  end

  class ConstantParse < ParseUnit
    attr_reader :value

    def initialize(value, overallIndex, nestLevel, indexInLevel)
      super(overallIndex, nestLevel, indexInLevel)
      @value = value
    end
  end

  class OperatorParse < ParseUnit
    attr_reader :operator
    attr_reader :priority

    def initialize(operator, overallIndex, nestLevel, indexInLevel)
      super(overallIndex, nestLevel, indexInLevel)
      @operator = operator
      @priority = OperatorInfo.operators[operator]
    end
  end

  class VariableParse < ParseUnit
    attr_reader :name

    def initialize(name, overallIndex, nestLevel, indexInLevel)
      super(overallIndex, nestLevel, indexInLevel)
      @name = name
    end
  end

  def parseTokens (tokens)
    ret = []
    nestLevel = 0
    indexes = [0]
    overallIndex = 0
    tokens.each do | t | 
      # can be operator, constant number, paren, variable 
      # puts "curToken is #{t}"

      case t       
      #operator
      when OperatorInfo.operators.keys.include?(t).to_s == 'true' ? t : ''
        ret.push OperatorParse.new t, overallIndex, nestLevel, indexes[nestLevel]
          overallIndex += 1
          indexes[nestLevel] += 1 
      # is a constant number
      when /\A\d+\z/        
        ret.push ConstantParse.new t.to_i, overallIndex, nestLevel, indexes[nestLevel]
        overallIndex += 1
        indexes[nestLevel] += 1
      when '('
        nestLevel += 1
        if indexes.length <= nestLevel
          indexes.push(0)
        end
      when ')'
        nestLevel -= 1
      #variable
      when String
        ret.push VariableParse.new t, overallIndex, nestLevel, indexes[nestLevel]
        overallIndex += 1
        indexes[nestLevel] += 1
      else
        puts "error in parse tokens with token #{t}"
      end
    end
    ret
  end

  class OperatorNode
    attr_reader :operator
    attr_reader :left
    attr_reader :right

    def initialize(operator, left, right)
      @left = left
      @right = right
      @operator = operator
      @priority = OperatorInfo.operators[operator] 
    end
  end

  def partition(parsedTokens)
    opTokens = parsedTokens.select { |token| token.is_a?(OperatorParse) }
    op = leastPrecedentOp opTokens
    left = parsedTokens.select { |x| x.overallIndex < op.overallIndex }
    right = parsedTokens.select { |x| x.overallIndex > op.overallIndex }
    OperatorNode.new op, left, right
  end

  def leastPrecedentOp opTokens
    if opTokens.length == 1 
      return opTokens[0]
    end
    # todo dry out this sort with the next one
    sortedByNestLevel = opTokens.sort_by { |x| x.nestLevel }
    nestLevelTies = sortedByNestLevel.select { |x| x.nestLevel == sortedByNestLevel[0].nestLevel }
    if nestLevelTies.length == 1
      return nestLevelTies[0]
    end
    sortedByPriority = nestLevelTies.sort_by { |x| x.priority }
    priorityTies = sortedByPriority.select { |x| x.priority == sortedByPriority[0].priority }
    if priorityTies.length == 1
      return priorityTies[0]
    end
    sortedByIndexInLevel = priorityTies.sort_by { |x| x.indexInLevel * -1 }
    sortedByIndexInLevel[0]
  end

  def buildTree(opNode)
    # puts opNode
    # base case
    leftIsSingle = opNode.left.length == 1
    rightIsSingle = opNode.right.length == 1
    if leftIsSingle && rightIsSingle
      return OperatorNode.new opNode.operator.operator, opNode.left, opNode.right   
    end
    # recursive call
    leftRet = nil
    if leftIsSingle
      leftRet = opNode.left[0]
    else
      leftPart = partition opNode.left
      leftRet = buildTree leftPart
    end

    rightRet = nil
    if rightIsSingle
      rightRet = opNode.right[0]
    else
      rightPart = partition opNode.right
      rightRet = buildTree rightPart
    end

    # combine and return
    OperatorNode.new opNode.operator.operator, leftRet, rightRet
  end

  def calculateRecursive node
    # base case
    if isLeaf? node, nil
      return getValue node
    end    
    leftIsLeaf = isLeaf? node, node.left
    rightIsLeaf = isLeaf? node, node.right
    if leftIsLeaf && rightIsLeaf
      if node.operator == OperatorInfo.assignmentOperator
        return calculateImpl node.operator, node.left[0].name, (getValue node.right)
      end
      leftVal = getValue node.left
      rightVal = getValue node.right
      return calculateImpl node.operator, leftVal, rightVal
    end
    # recursive call
    leftResult = nil
    if leftIsLeaf && node.operator != OperatorInfo.assignmentOperator
      leftResult = getValue node.left
    elsif leftIsLeaf && node.operator
      leftResult = node.left.name
    else
      leftResult = calculateRecursive node.left
    end
    rightResult = nil
    if rightIsLeaf
      rightResult = getValue node.right
    else
      rightResult = calculateRecursive node.right
    end
    # combine and return
    result = calculateImpl node.operator, leftResult, rightResult
    result
  end

  def isLeaf?(parent, node)
    # if parent
    isConstant = node.is_a? ConstantParse 
    if node.is_a? Array 
      isConstant = node[0].is_a? ConstantParse
    end
    isVariable = node.is_a? VariableParse
    if node.is_a? Array 
      isVariable = node[0].is_a? VariableParse
    end
    return isConstant || isVariable
  end

  def getValue node
    nodeVal = nil
    if node.is_a? Array
      nodeVal = node[0]
    else
      nodeVal = node
    end
    if nodeVal.is_a? ConstantParse
      return nodeVal.value
    end
    if nodeVal.is_a? VariableParse
      if @variables.key? nodeVal.name
        return @variables[nodeVal.name]
      end
      return nodeVal.name
    end
  end

  def calculateImpl(operator, left, right)
    #puts "#{left} #{operator} #{right}"
    case operator
    when '+'
      return left + right
    when '-'
      return left - right
    when '/'
      return left.to_f / right
    when '*'
      return left * right
    when '%'
      return left % right
    when '='
      @variables[left] = right
      return right
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @variables = {}
  end  

  def tokenize program
    return [] if program == ''
    regex = /\s*([-+*\/\%=\(\)]|[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*|[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s*/
    program.scan(regex).select { |s| !(s =~ /^\s*$/) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

What you mentioned about removing parentheses like you did in `def input expr` method definition, in general [is a bad practice](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#method-parens). My suggestions:

- Start running [`rubocop -a your_path/file.rb`](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop#installation) to auto-correct most of style problems in your code.
- Fix manually variable names like `parsedTokens` or method names like `parseTokens` to be [snake cased](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars).
- Most of the time, there are no good reasons to use [class variables](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-class-vars) like you did in `@@operators`. Actually, I'd move those vars. out of `OperatorInfo` and remove that class definition, then defining them as constants in the main class as:

```
class Interpreter
  # .freeze is to really define these variables as constants (immutables)
  OPERATORS = { '=' => 0, '+' => 1, '-' => 1, '*' => 2, '/' => 2, '%' => 2 }.freeze
  ASSIGNMENT_OPERATOR = '='.freeze
```

- You can define readers in a single call, like:

```
  class ParseUnit
    attr_reader :overall_index, :nest_level, :index_in_level
```

- If possible, define sub classes like `OperatorNode` in separate files. If not, defining them under `private` [isn't really effective](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/UselessAccessModifier):

```
class Interpreter
  def self.calling_inner_class
    OperatorNode
  end

  private
  class OperatorNode
    # ...
  end
end

Interpreter.calling_inner_class # Interpreter::OperatorNode
# This shouldn't work for private classes
Interpreter::OperatorNode # => Interpreter::OperatorNode
```

An option to make them really private is adding [`private_constant`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/private_constant) to every class definition like:

```
class Interpreter
  def self.calling_inner_class
    # This operates normally
    OperatorNode
  end

  class OperatorNode
    # ...
  end
  private_constant :OperatorNode
end

Interpreter.calling_inner_class # Interpreter::OperatorNode
# Throwing an error, which is correct
Interpreter::OperatorNode # NameError: private constant Interpreter::OperatorNode referenced
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! I appreciate it!

Comment: @reggaeguitar after looking again my answer, I realised the last part wasn't correct at all, so I removed everything related with [private classes within `self` blocks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/242932/revisions) as it's not really defining the classes as privates. Cheers